# ansible set_fact not accessible

Tags: ansible

i have this ansible playbook

```
- name: set var small
  set_fact:
    iops_price = 41538
    ram_price_id = 32438
    second_san_price_id = 32926
    os_price_id = 49061
  when: plan|lower == 'small'

- name: aa
  command: echo "{{iops_price}}"
```

it fails because it says iops_price is not defined, this is the output:

```
TASK [set var small] ***********************************************************
task path: /home/hanna/proj/db2onc-deploy/db.yml:98
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"_raw_params": "iops_price = 41538  ram_price_id = 32438 second_san_price_id = 32926 os_price_id = 49061"}, "changed": false}

TASK [aa] **********************************************************************
task path: /home/hanna/proj/db2onc-deploy/db.yml:107
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'iops_price' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/hanna/proj/db2onc-deploy/db.yml': line 107, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n      - name: aa\n        ^ here\n"}
```

it turned out that the fact that i set is accessible via _raw_params, which is equivalent to

```
_raw_params = "iops_price = 41538 ram_price_id = 32438 second_san
_price_id = 32926 os_price_id = 49061"
```

this is not what i wanted, i actually want to set those individual variables, anybody has any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often I find that in YAML it doesn't parse '=' as fields if there is a space around it. Try:

```
  set_fact:
    iops_price=41538
    ram_price_id=32438
    second_san_price_id=32926
    os_price_id=49061
  when: plan|lower == 'small'
```

Comment: It's not about YAML actually. It's an Ansible ability to parse `key=value` parameters (no space between `=`) from raw parameters string, and you just use YAML ability to split one continuous line into multiple lines. If you want to specify parameters in YAML way – there is only one possible delimiter - `:`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use colons (`:`)  instead of equal (`=`) signs in set_fact.

This should work:

```
- name: set var small
  set_fact:
    iops_price: 41538
    ram_price_id: 32438
    second_san_price_id: 32926
    os_price_id: 49061
  when: plan|lower == 'small'

- name: aa
  command: echo "{{iops_price}}"
```